# Different color on the bar chart in react native

Tags: react-native, charts

Hi I want to create a rectangular bar chart in my react native app. Something like below image

[image]

I used react-native-chart-kit but its having only one color configuration. I was googling through other carts but did not find the right one to satisfy the referred image. Is there any example with any bar chart library which can be helpful to me

Answer (score 0):

Excuse my code formatting, navigating my way in Stackoverflow.

This is a code example I have used before, change of padding and color is up too you.

```
/* App.js */
var React = require('react');
var Component = React.Component;
var CanvasJSReact = require('./canvasjs.react');
var CanvasJS = CanvasJSReact.CanvasJS;
var CanvasJSChart = CanvasJSReact.CanvasJSChart;

class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.toggleDataSeries = this.toggleDataSeries.bind(this);
    }
    toggleDataSeries(e){
        if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dazaSeries.visible) {
            e.dataSeries.visible = false;
        }
        else{
            e.dataSeries.visible = true;
        }
        this.chart.render();
    }
    render() {
        const options = {
            animationEnabled: true,
            title:{
                text: "All Time Summer Olympic Medals"
            },
            legend: {
                verticalAlign: "center",
                horizontalAlign: "right",
                reversed: true,
                cursor: "pointer",
                fontSize: 16,
                itemclick: this.toggleDataSeries
            },
            toolTip: {
                shared: true
            },
            data: [
            {
                type: "stackedColumn100",
                name: "Gold",
                showInLegend: true,
                color: "#D4AF37",
                dataPoints: [
                    { label: "United States", y:1118},
                    { label: "Soviet Union", y:473},
                    { label: "Great Britain", y:273},
                    { label: "France", y:243},
                    { label: "Germany", y:269},
                    { label: "Italy", y:243},
                    { label: "Sweden", y:195},
                    { label: "China", y:236},
                    { label: "Russia", y:194},
                    { label: "East Germany", y:192}
                ]
            },
            {
                type: "stackedColumn100",
                name: "Silver",
                showInLegend: true,
                color: "#C0C0C0",
                dataPoints: [
                    { label: "United States",   y: 897},
                    { label: "Soviet Union", y: 376},
                    { label: "Great Britain", y: 299},
                    { label: "France", y: 272},
                    { label: "Germany", y: 272},
                    { label: "Italy",   y: 212},
                    { label: "Sweden", y: 210},
                    { label: "China",   y: 189},
                    { label: "Russia", y: 156},
                    { label: "East Germany", y: 165}
                ]
            },
            {
                type: "stackedColumn100",
                name: "Bronze",
                showInLegend: true,
                color: "#CD7F32",
                dataPoints: [
                    { label: "United States", y: 789},
                    { label: "Soviet Union", y: 355},
                    { label: "Great Britain", y: 303},
                    { label: "France", y: 310},
                    { label: "Germany", y: 283},
                    { label: "Italy", y: 236},
                    { label: "Sweden", y: 233},
                    { label: "China", y: 174},
                    { label: "Russia", y: 187},
                    { label: "East Germany", y: 162}
                ]
            }
            ]
        }
        return (
        <div>
            <CanvasJSChart options = {options}
                 onRef={ref => this.chart = ref}
            />
            {/*You can get reference to the chart instance as shown above using onRef. This allows you to access all chart properties and methods*/}
        </div>
        );
    }
}
module.exports = App;
```